# No garbage collector has time to collect SoftReference, always OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, soft-references

Tried all garbage collectors, a million different combinations of settings.
But the result is always the same - OutOfMemoryError.

Can anyone tell which garbage collector will be able to timely remove objects referenced by soft references

Example emulator code below

```
package com;

import java.lang.ref.SoftReference;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class SoftReferenceCollector {

    private static class Data {
        public long[] l = new long[100];
    }

    private List<SoftReference<Data>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public void startFillCollection(int durationInSec) {
        long i = 0;

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long end = start + durationInSec * 1000;
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
            list.add(new SoftReference<>(new Data()));
            ++i;
            if (i % 10000 == 0) {
                sleep(1);
                if (i % 1_000_000 == 0)
                    sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }

    private void sleep(long millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
        }
    }
}


public class Main6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SoftReferenceCollector softReferenceCollector = new SoftReferenceCollector();
        softReferenceCollector.startFillCollection(11240);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Referents` (Object referenced by the `SoftReference`) are being cleared by the GC before throwing an OOO Exception.

But what is not being garbaged collected are the `SoftReference` objects themselves. They are objects too and they consume heap memory. They are all being held in memory by the list. GC only clears the object they point to, that is the `referent`.

Run your JVM with `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`. This flag will dump the heap before the OOO so you can later analyze it. You can use Eclipse Memory Analizer.

You can also try `-XX:+PrintReferenceGC` flag which will print some informatión regarding time spent during gc cycle by cleaning those kind of references.

Comment: usuario, Thank you, you are absolutely right. And what is the best way to check that the garbage collector manages to remove soft links? After all, simply replacing list.add(new SoftReference<>(new Data())); to new SoftReference<>(new Data()); we will also get SoftReference objects that are easily accessible for the collector

Comment: SoftReference objects are being strong referenced so the only way the GC will clean them is to make them unreachable. Do not store their reference as you have suggested or remove their reference from the List. Not sure what you are trying to achieve but you should take a look at [WeakHashmap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) for inspiration.

Comment: usuario, thank you

Comment: usuario, I see you have a powerful experience related to working with memory, maybe you can answer a question from this topic  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70727397/when-i-manually-start-the-garbage-collector-from-visualvm-everything-is-ok-bu)  I will be very grateful