# When I manually start the garbage collector from visualvm - everything is OK, but the regular GC does not collect garbage

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

A strange situation,

i use java: 1.8.0_271  and tomcat: 9.0.39

there are a number of services on tomcat, after a certain time I notice an OutOfMemoryError error in the logs, and indeed all the memory is used up. At the same time, if I manually start garbage collection from visualvm, then the memory is released.

The dump does not show anything, analyzed JProfiler and MAT - it seems to cut off the used memory, leaving only a little free that remains.

And yet, after restarting all the services individually, the memory is still not released, you have to restart tomcat

my GP parameters (I have experimented with others but to no avail)

```
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem
-XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=250
-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
-verbose:gc
-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime
```

And most importantly, when I try to upload a dump to a profiler (MAT and others), I get a message.

```
Removed 15 875 439 unreachable objects using 1 700 938 414 bytes
```

Why can't he display these objects, I need to see exactly them

What could it be?

Comment: Update your question with which JRE you are using.

Comment: edited, indicated the versions of java and tomcat

Comment: maybe you have some memory leak - are you using some InputStream or such that you don't close?

Comment: J Asgarov, It really looks like a leak, only the server has 20 old services with tens of thousands of lines of code. But even in this case, with classic leaks, after a piecewise restart of each service, there should be a release of memory, but this happens only after restarting Tomcat or when starting manual cleaning in visualVM. I read somewhere about a leak in ClassLoader. Maybe someone heard about it, similar to this case?

Comment: Yes, classloader leaks are a thing.  But the solution is the same.  Find the leak, fix the leak.

Comment: Try to configure the garbage collector to be more aggressive, or run another JRE. The default gc settings  java 8 is delaying collection quite much, and even when out of memory does not really reclaim everything it could.

Comment: Stephen C
if this is a leak in the program code, then why is memory freed up when manually assembling into a visualvm?

Comment: Just another Java programmer, Yes, I'm just trying to set up the GC, thanks!

Comment: How can I find a leak if the dump does not show the chunk of memory occupied by the uncollected garbage?

Comment: Please complete the question with: **1**all memory related JVM flags (You can get the complete list from VisualVM, Overview Tab or Jconsole VM Summary tab). **2** Complete OOO Exception error message, as there are many root causes for them. Each one provides different log output **3** Some logs from an Old and Young Collection in order to see phases and time spended. Enable them using `-XX:+PrintGCDetails`. Specially relevant are the ones before the OOO. **4** Enable this Flag `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` in order to get a Heap Dump just before OOO so you can inspect it with MAT later

Comment: @usuario
Thanks for answering
When I try to upload a dump to a profiler (MAT and others), I get a message:
 Removed 15 875 439 unreachable objects using 1 700 938 414 bytes .
 That is how much memory is occupied by garbage that cannot be cleaned.

Comment: And I don’t understand until the end of the moment why the standard garbage collection does not occur (memory is released only after restarting the tomcat), and when you press the button in the profiler - garbage collect - everything happens normally?

Comment: @Thomazzz About `Removed 15 875 439 unreachable objects using 1 700 938 414 bytes` please read this [link](https://wiki.eclipse.org/MemoryAnalyzer/FAQ#How_to_analyse_unreachable_objects). They are dead objects in the heap the moment you took the heap dump. That is not related to an OOO Exception.

Comment: @usuario So the GC itself cannot clean up these objects, this is the reason OOO

Comment: Unreachable objects are always reclaimed by GC, they are not the problem. OOO Exceptions are thrown because of too much live objecs, not dead ones. Please provide some gc logs or the complete OOO Exception trace.

Comment: @usuario, you helped me a lot in understanding the work of all this mechanics, thank you very much

Comment: If your web application(s) fail to shut-down cleanly, you can "pin" the web application's `ClassLoader` in memory, which will keep all of those previously-loaded classes in memory and, potentially, other data as well (static caches, etc.) forever. Restarting/deploying/etc the web application just makes the problem worse. You need to test your application in a dev environment by running it, using it, then stopping it and using the Tomcat "manager" application to "check for leaks" which will tell you if your application is leaking on shutdown. Fix anything you find.

Comment: @Christopher Schultz, Thanks for your reply. But as I understand it, then the garbage collection that we call by the button in visualvm would not work?  In my case, when manually pressing the garbage cleanup button, a real cleanup occurs, i.e. as far as I understand, this is still not a leak, but the fact that the garbage collector does not have time to clean up oldgen and you need to further configure it, for example, allocate more space for youngen and increase the number of collector passes to transfer objects to the next phase

Comment: @Thomazzz I apologize if I didn't quite understand the circumstances, here. What you described sounded like a classic ClassLoader pinning problem. I was confused by this statement: *it seems to cut off the used memory, leaving only a little free that remains*. I'm not sure if using VisualVM to trigger a GC run is any different than calling System.gc() or allowing the GC to run automatically when it thinks it's a good time to cleanup. What error message do you get with the OOME? Not all OOMEs are the same.